# Стоит ли использовать массивы массивов для обработки данных ?

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d

[image]

[ссылка](http://i60.fastpic.ru/big/2013/0825/1f/d928fc76142fe9246a683a5ee215d21f.jpg) на изображение.

Есть некоторое количество обьектов, у каждого обьекта есть характеристики типа (int) с ключом (string) все эти обькты хранятся в БД. Характеристики подразделяются на два типа: важные данные, все остальные. Эти данные формируются в массив. Далее происходит обьединение массивов этих данных в единственный. Из всех этих массивов от всех обьектов мы формирует два массива в котором уже будут массивы нужных данных и соответственно "ненужных". Эти два массива формируются в один и далее используются уже в каких либо методах. Не хотелось бы использовать такое количество данных оперируя ими по одиночке поэтому: Стоит ли создавать такую вложенность массивов ?  Есть еще какие либо способы обработки многочисленного количества данных ? При этом хотел использовать <ключ,значение> чтобы хоть как то различать обьекты, но в массивах недопустимо хранить словари...

Comment: Нет. (...)

Comment: @Flammable, каким образом мне лучше поступить в таком случае ?

Comment: Завернуть все это в соответствующие классы, например.

Comment: т.е для каждого обьекта свой класс ?

Comment: Да, но классы делайте универсальными.

Comment: Вполне нормально иметь для каждого типа данных свой класс. Разумеется, если разница между двумя видами данных для вашей задачи несущественна, их можно «склеить» в один класс. Это представляет какую-то проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, о какой обработке идет речь. Если нужно искать по строке, то я бы хранил в первом столбце таблицы хэш строки, а во втором xml со всеми остальными данными. Даже наверно xml надо хранить в виде XDocument, записанного в varbinary поле.